# What is Money multiplier deposit or MMD?

Tags: india, banking, bank-account, online-banking

What is money multiplier deposit or MMD? How it works in Indian bank?

Answer (score 1):

It is a combination product where the funds in savings account are linked to Fixed deposit. As the money is in fixed deposit, the interest rates are better. If the funds in savings account go below rs 10,000 the fixed deposits are broken automatically and credited to savings account.

Comment: Only ICICI provides this?